# can i use a loop in a condition in C

Tags: c

```
do{
printf("Entrer le nombre\n");
scanf("%d",&o);
}while(o!=T[i]);
```

just want to test all the array T[] and see if the number "o" given by the user exist in any case of the array

Comment: Please restrain from debugging requests and personal tutoring requests here on Stack Overflow. All you need to do is to formulate a concrete programming question, that's your entry-card.

Comment: @staticx In this case, the "live code" is not excessive for a person answering to deal with.

Comment: `do /* ... */ while (!inarray(o, T, sizeof T/sizeof *T));`

Comment: Loop in a condition...? This code shows a condition inside a loop. Aren't you simply asking how to iterate through the array?

Comment: please clarify what your are asking and what is not working in your current code

Comment: Cosidering that there are languages that support this kind of operation it is not an unreasonable question.

Answer (score 2):

> can i use a loop in a condition in C?

No, you can't, a function is needed, something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int fn(int *arr, int n, int x)
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (arr[i] == x) return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

int main(void)
{
    int o, arr[] = {1, 2, 3};
    size_t n = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);

    do {
        printf("Entrer le nombre\n");
        scanf("%d", &o);
    } while (fn(arr, n, o));
    return 0;
}
```

Or using `bsearch` and a comparison function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int comp(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    return (*(int *)a - *(int *)b);
}

int main(void)
{
    int o, arr[] = {1, 2, 3};
    size_t n = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);

    do{
        printf("Entrer le nombre\n");
        scanf("%d", &o);
    } while (!bsearch(&o, arr, n, sizeof(int), comp));
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot use a loop in a condition in C.

However, you can define a function which checks if `o` is equal to any element of array `T`, and return `1` if it exists. Then you call this function in the condition and check for equality ot `1`